# How would i add the ability to upload a picture to be a posts background on the show page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So in **rails** I have post **CRUDability** made so far, I have markdown on my posts.
When I create the posts I also want to have the ability to upload a picture which will be displayed as the background of the post on the show page when the user clicks this. I know the question is a bit broad and could possibly be refined but I wouldn't know how to word it.

Comment: checkout carrierwave gem or paperclip gem..these would enable to upload a pic and show on page

Comment: So those gems would allow me to store the images, how would i then be able to take that picture i upload in the post creation stage and add it as a background for the post background?